# MongoDB WinningPlan IDHACK

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

For the below query:

```
db.restaurants.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5aabce4f827d70999ae5f5f7")}).explain()
```

I'm getting the below query plan:

```
/* 1 */
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "test.restaurants",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "_id" : {
            "$eq" : ObjectId("5aabce4f827d70999ae5f5f7")
        }
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "IDHACK"
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "CHNMCT136701L",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.6.3",
    "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
},
"ok" : 1.0
}
```

Now I have some questions on my mind. 
What is meant by `stage: IDHACK` ? How its different from COLLSCAN? Whether this has anything to do with performance optimization? If yes, what are the scenarios in which MongoDB goes for this `winningplan` ? If I create an index on `_id`, whether `IDHACK` will be replaced by the respective indexing plan?
Can anybody clarify this?

Comment: This is explained over at Database Administrators: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174345/what-is-plansummary-idhack

Answer (score 2):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16891

*The query idhack path (a performance optimization to reduce planning/execution overhead for operations with query predicates of the form {_id: })*

COLLSCAN doesn't use an index. IDHACK uses the _id index.

yes it does have to do with performance optimization.