# Is using limit(1) improving query performances mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

A simple question, let's have this query : `user_result = db.users.find({"_id": "anyID"})`

Is it more performant than `user_result = db.users.find({"_id": "anyID"}).limit(1)` if i know that this query should return only one result.

Comment: To retrieve only one document use `findOne`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare the results if `.explain()` you will find that the winning plan in both cases is `IDHACK`.
`.limit(1)` will not provide any perf gains.

```
db.users.find({"_id": "anyID"}).limit(1).explain()
db.users.find({"_id": "anyID"}).explain()
```

Similar question on [MongoDB WinningPlan IDHACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390034/mongodb-winningplan-idhack)

Also, you probably want to do a [findOne()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) in this case.

```
db.users.findOne({"_id": "anyID"})
```

Keep in mind that the return value of `findOne()` differs from that of `find()`. FindOne returns the document, whereas Find returns a cursor.